# Convert current date to nth

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I convert `October 24, 2018` to `24th of October, 2018`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a formula. I don't know if there is a function ready-to-use. In english, you can do something like this:

```
NumberVar DayIn := Day ({YourTable.YourDate});
Totext (DayIn , 0 )
& (if DayIn in 4 to 20 then 'th' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 1 then 'st' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 2 then 'nd' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 3 then 'rd' else 'th')
& " of "
& Totext ({YourTable.YourDate}, "MMMM, yyyy")
```

Comment: I don't use table. I only use current dates. 

I don't know what to put here -> **({YourTable.YourDate})**

Comment: You can change it by PrintDate: Day(PrintDate).

Answer (score 2):

This will require a Custom Style applied to the field that displays the date.  To create this right click the field and click "Format Field".  On the Date tab of the Format Editor click the Customize button.

You should now see the Custom Style window.

In the Format group set Month to use the long name of the month.
In the Order group click the radio button for DMY.
In the Separators group click the X-2 button for the field labeled "First:" and enter the following formula:

```
If Right(ToText(Day({GLPREPOST.START_DATE}),0,""),1) = "1" Then
    "st of "
Else If Right(ToText(Day({GLPREPOST.START_DATE}),0,""),1) = "2" Then
    "nd of "
Else If Right(ToText(Day({GLPREPOST.START_DATE}),0,""),1) = "3" Then
    "rd of "
Else 
    "th of "
```

Replace the `{GLPREPOST.START_DATE}` with the reference to the field in your database that contains the date you are formatting.

You will also want to enter a space into the Separators group for the field labeled "Second:".

Click the OK button to save your custom style.

At this point your date should be displayed as requested.  :)

Comment: Hey as I observed the code you gave, the 1 and 2 ends with "th".

Comment: @Drin My apologies.  There were 2 issues with the formula I provided earlier.  crNumericDay was out of scope in the separators group and needed to be replaced with a reference to the database field.  The conversion of the Day part of the date to text was also adding a decimal and 2 digits after the decimal that conflicted with the RIGHT function.  I have edited my answer with a new formula that should work better for you now.